# Can I mark a field as inaccessible within a Java class (the defining class itself)?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-native-interface, modifier

In a JNI environment, I want my Java class to contain some private fields, which I want to explicitly mark as "off limits" for Java access, so only my native code can use them.

So basically I have

```
public class Example() {
   private int var;
   private int varInternalState;

   public native void nativeMethod(...);
   public void otherMethod() { ... }
}
```

`nativeMethod()` needs some internal state information per object, which I want to keep in `varInternalState`. (I know how to do this; it works). But I want to mark `varInternalState` as "off limits" for `otherMethod()`, because it makes absolutely no sense to access it from Java, and I want to get a compiler error - or at least warning - if my future self or someone unfamiliar with the code acidentially reads or writes it.

Declaring it `private` doesn't help, because this is about accesses from the class itself, not from other classes.

And because of some Reflection magic, I don't want to give a name like `doNotEverTouchThis` to the internal variable; I'd like to stay free in naming that thing.

I think there's no keyword in Java to do this as I can't explicitly mark fields as synthetic, so I guess Annotations might help - however, I know next to nothing about them, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if possible.

So, is there a clever way to declare `varInternalState`, or an existing annotation library that lets me do something like `@Inaccessible private int varInternalState`, which makes the compiler spit an error whenever I try to read/write the field?

Comment: Why don't you mark it as final and set it once in the constructor? Do you need to change it? How frequent?

Comment: That's a start, but won't prevent me from reading it. The JNI method will read and write to it, more or less whenever it's called, but Java shouldn't.

Comment: In such case, I will say use inheritance, move this variable in a separate class, make it private and only put those methods which can access the variable in that class. Extend this class to create other classes.

Comment: What actual harm will it cause if the Java code ever reads the field? Wouldn’t a name reflecting the actual purpose (like `fileHandle` or `nativeFeatureByteOffset`) be enough to tell the Java developer that its value has no use for the Java code? I’d expect the field to be annotated with [`@Native`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Native.html) anyway which tells even more. That’s not preventing access from within the declaring class, but distrusting the author of the class regarding their own class is a bit pointless.